# Inside Jira how do I see boards from multiple projects in a single drop down?

Tags: jira

We have 2 projects with the proper boards displaying their workflows accurately. Project A has one board.
Project B has three boards.

When i'm inside Project A i cannot see the boards from Project B and vice versa. I would like the 'boards' tab to show the boards from all projects so i can jump between them quickly.

The projects have very distinctive workflows.

Answer (score 1):

When you **create a Board**, it will ask if you want to create a board **based off of a pre-existing project or projects, select this option**, and select all of the projects that you want to have represented in the Board.

You can use **filter** to only display tasks from projects that you want.

You can read more in https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/jira-agile-resources/jira-agile-faq/how-do-i-get-a-board-to-point-to-multiple-projects

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to have visibility to multiple boards in one view, without having to change screens, I don't think Jira gives you this right of the bat. But you could try an add-on. Here is one I think does this.

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/early-bird-planner-prod/cloud/overview